# Apply str.replace() to string but error says it's a float

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas to strip a '$' out of some strings in a column.

```
df['Amount'].dtypes` --> `dtype('O')
```

So, I figure I can do string modification now:

```
df['Amount'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('$', ''))
```

I get the error: `'float' object has no attribute 'replace'`.

Why would the type "Object" (string) but be "float" when I'm operating on it?

Answer (score 4):

Object doesn't mean **string**, it means not a homogeneous vectorizable dtype.

You can use:

```
df['Amount'].astype(str).str.replace('$', '')
```

Comment: That explains, thx